# What is the correct RESTful implementation in WebAPI2?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Essentially I have found a waste number of opinions on this topic, but none that convinces me what is correct. More specifically I have the following questions:

Singular or Plural or both

- Is there even a correct and a wrong way?

  Standards and conventions exists for a reason, I don´t believe I will ever settle for - *it´s just a matter of taste*. Isn´t there any guideline or standard? No authority completing Fieldings work?

What IHttpActionResults to return? And what should they contain?

- Get - return Ok();
- Post - return Created();
- Put - return (Put? Ok?)
- Delete - return (Deleted? Ok?)

What to return in Created(**location**)?

Assuming the Controller route is 'api/v1/model', should it be

- '/{id}'?
- 'api/v1/model/{id}'?
- 'http://www.mywebapi.com/api/v1/model/{id}'?

I ask these questions because I frequently run into conflicts about how to best implement APIs.

Comment: +1 This is a good question. Could you please elaborate what you mean when you say "Assuming the Controller route is 'api/v1/model', should it be"..etc The controller route starts from the domain (www.mywebapi.com/) so whats the difference between option nr 2 and nr 3?

Comment: The `location` parameter in the `Created()` method should be a reference to the current _item_ right? The difference between 2 and 3 should then be obvious I think. #2 will assume that the API consumer itself will provided for the right part of the URL and #3 - the entire and full URL will be returned. The `location` parameter is just a plain string and there is no _".NET-auto-complete-route-to-url-conversion-thingie"_ going on as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, Now I see. When you read the question the "Created(location)" line stand for itself. You should remove the line break or rewrite them. Good question though,  If the api is consumed from different domains then I would return full URL.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** *Singular or Plural or both*

Never use both. Use either one. Use noun but not verbs.

Do not use verbs:

> /getAllCars
>   /createNewCar
>   /deleteAllRedCars

Do not mix up singular and plural nouns. Keep it simple and use only plural nouns for all resources.

```
/cars instead of /car
/users instead of /user
/products instead of /product
```

Now if you see below, it will make more sense:

> GET /tickets - Retrieves a list of tickets
>   GET /tickets/12 - Retrieves a specific ticket
>   POST /tickets - Creates a new ticket
>   PUT /tickets/12 - Updates ticket #12
>   PATCH /tickets/12 - Partially updates ticket #12
>   DELETE /tickets/12 - Deletes ticket #12

If a resource is related to another resource use subresources.

> GET /cars/711/drivers/ Returns a list of drivers for car 711

**Q:** *What to return in Created(location)?*

200 OK - Response to a successful GET, PUT, PATCH or DELETE. Can also be used for a POST that doesn't result in a creation.

201 Created - Response to a POST that results in a creation. Should be combined with a [Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) pointing to the location of the new resource

Provide clarity on your last question and I'll update my answer accordingly.

There're no defined standards for REST and everyone uses best practices as per their need. However I would suggest you to go through this [PDF](https://pages.apigee.com/rs/351-WXY-166/images/ebook-2013-03-wad.pdf) from apigee.com which lists down the best practices for REST API and what each of the big player i.e Facebook, twitter etc uses.

Comment: Should `location` be the absolute url or the left part uri? What should the client expect the `location` to be?

Comment: Another issue is that is not always clear how the relations (and thus the routes should work), consider a many-to-many relations... where `api/accounts/{id}/user` could be one option but also `api/users/{id}/accounts` which would **semantically** lead us into an infinite loop where this would be appropriate `api/accounts/{id}/user/accounts/{id}/user/accounts/{id}[..]`.

Comment: If you refer the Location Header link in my post, it says absolute URI.

Comment: Why would there be an infinite loop?

Comment: Because an `account` belongs to a `user` and a `user` has `accounts`, it is a many-to-many relationship, which makes it unclear which is the correct approach; `accounts/{id}/user` or `users/{id}/accounts`.

Comment: Both are valid: 
accounts/{id}/user**s**  - returns all the user having access to that particular account
users/{id}/accounts - returns all the accounts which user can access to.

Comment: Most of your ideas and responses I see as very sound and I agrer with them, but what I was looking for was one set of standard definitions and I still see a few architectural ambiguities.